# Почему при использовании Quip для комментариев в Modx Revolution в тексте комментария сохраняется "0"?

Tags: modx, revo

MODX Revolution версии 2.6.5-pl

Quip версия 2.3.3-pl

Отправляется комментарий с сайта, в тексте и на русском, и на английском пробую писать, сохраняется всегда 0. И тоже самое в административной панели, редактируешь комментарий, в тексте что угодно пишешь, сохраняется "0". Кто встречался с таким?

Comment: Привет. Такая же проблема, Вы решили ее?

Comment: У меня данная проблема так и не решилась, возникала она в момент сохранения комментария в базу, в файле core/components/quip/processors/web/comment/create.php есть строка с очищением комментария от запрещенных символов, но удаление этой строки и какие-либо правки не помогли, может вам это поможет (возможно проблема как раз в <field key="body" dbtype="text" phptype="text" null="false" default="" /> в файле quip.mysql.schema.xml как пишут в комментарии, потому что что-то именно в процессе сохранения). В итоге установили компонент Ticket и там всё работало.

Comment: предполагаю что в в бд записывается результат какой-то не успешной операции с комментов или это результат преобразования так как `0`, а не `1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно проблема в версии `php`, необходимо сменить для "`body`" `phptype` с `text` на `string`

Попробуйте так:

Файлы (`quip.mysql.schema.xml` и `quip.sqlsrv.schema.xml`) расположены примерно:

`core/components/quip/model/schema/quip.mysql.schema.xml`
`core/components/quip/model/schema/quip.sqlsrv.schema.xml`

Ищете строку:

```
<field key="body" dbtype="text" phptype="text" null="false" default="" />
```

Меняете на:

```
<field key="body" dbtype="text" phptype="string" null="false" default="" />
```

Файл (`quipcomment.map.inc.php`) расположен примерно (2 места, в зависимости от базы):

```
core/components/quip/model/quip/sqlsrv/quipcomment.map.inc.php
core/components/quip/model/quip/mysql/quipcomment.map.inc.php
```

Ищете строку:

```
'body' => 
 array (
  'dbtype' => 'text',
  'phptype' => 'text',
  'null' => false,
  'default' => '',
),
```

и тут меняем

```
'phptype' => 'string',
```

P.S. От себя замечу, компонент очень старый, последнее обновление от 2012 года, советую использовать более современные компоненты комментирования (Ticket и т.п.)

Comment: Была такая же проблема.
Реально помогло, спасибо!